# Update part of Android app

Tags: android

When I open Playstore updates page many apps are having update size very small compared to the actual size of the app. For example, WhatsApp have a size 50 MB but its one update is having size 8MB.I have an app which have some in built media files and hence having a size of 70 MB. But when I fix some minor bugs and update the app in Playstore it still showing the update size as 70MB. How can I update only part of the application which I have changed into Playstore.

Comment: play store does that automatically, they compare each files and prepares the update patch.

Comment: But every time I have to download around 70MB even if change is in 1 file in the latest version.

Comment: please see my answer

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do anything special to reduce the app size If you use the newest (at least **2.2+**) **Android Studio/Android Gradle Plugin**.Play store compares file by file and makes the patch apk. so the apk size will be reduced about 65%.

Read [this](https://www.androidheadlines.com/2016/12/google-play-gets-file-file-update-patching.html) and [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/51668/why-app-updates-download-entire-app-instead-of-only-updates) links for more info.

Please read [this](https://medium.com/google-developers/tracking-app-update-sizes-1a1f57634f7b) article about optimizing app update sizes.